# how to display dropdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to display a dropdown - in the dropdown I am displaying some items which are in selected state, remaining should be displayed in dropdwon.

Below is my code and array which I need to display in selected state

```js
var arr1 = [ 
        {id: 2, name: "name2"},
        {id: 3, name: "name3"},
        {id: 4, name: "name4"},
        {id: 5, name: "name5"}
    ];

var arr2 = [
        {id: 2, name: "name2" },
        {id: 3, name: "name3" },
    ];


$('#DropDown').html('');
let html = '<select id="selected"  name="selected[]"  multiple>';
for (let x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    let selected = "";
    if (arr2[j].id === arr1[x].id) {
      selected = "selected";
    }
    html = html + ' <option  value="' + arr1[x].id + '"' + selected + '>' +
      arr1[x].name + '</option>';
  }
}
html = html + '</select>';
$('#DropDown').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DropDown"></div>
```

in output, I want to show all arr1 items in the dropdown and arr2 elements in selected state.

Comment: what you have to achive ?? its working

Comment: I've converted your code, as-is to a snippet, with the *implied* HTML.  Please update to show the issue and please include the **expected result** as it seems to be working albeit adding all the items multiple times.

Comment: in dropdown items are showing repeatedly.that is the issue i am facing

Comment: in output, I want to show all arr1 items in the dropdown and arr2 elements in selected state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was you are adding option in for loop of `arr2`.

```
var arr1 = [ 
        {id: 2, name: "name2"},
        {id: 3, name: "name3"},
        {id: 4, name: "name4"},
        {id: 5, name: "name5"}
    ];

var arr2 = [
        {id: 2, name: "name2" },
        {id: 3, name: "name3" },
    ];


$('#DropDown').html('');
        let html = '<select id="selected"  name="selected[]"  multiple>';
        for (let x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {
            let selected = "";
            let arr1Id = arr1[x].id;
            let arr1Name = arr1[x].name;
            for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
               if (arr2[j].id === arr1[x].id) {
               selected = "selected";
             }
        }
        html = html + ' <option  value="' + arr1Id + '"' + selected + '>' +arr1Name + 
       '</option>';
    }
html = html + '</select>';
$('#DropDown').append(html);
```